# Determine in each case whether the given subset is a subgroup of $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$ a) {(1),(12345),(15432)}$
If we have ${(12345)(12345)=(13524) which is not in S therefore it is not subgroup$

$b){(1),(123),(132),(45),(123)(45),(132)(45)}$
I believe that this is a subgroup but is there another way to prove this other than going through all of the variations and showing that every possibility is indeed in the group?

Answer (score 0):

If you denote $a = (1\,2\,3), b = (4\,5)$ then you can see, that your set is
$$id, a, a^2, b, ab, a^2b.$$
It is obvious that $ab = ba$, so all possible combinations are $$a^kb^n.$$
Using the fact that $a^3 = b^2 = 0,$ we can show that distict combinations are produced by $$0 \leq k \leq 2, 0 \leq n \leq 1.$$
It is easy to see that your set contains all this combinations.